# BE QM marking SMD component

Tags: surface-mount

[image]Working on a board currently, but cannot find any info on what kind of component this is.

I have some suspicion/intuitive feel, but I`d like to be sure.

It appears to be a **SOT 89** package.

Anyone please.

Thank you.

Comment: A sharp photograph of the part in question is your best bet, preferably showing the designator on the PCB, if any.

Comment: what exactly is your question? ... it is difficult to provide an answer without a question ... maybe the answer is 42 ... lol

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thank you

Comment: Search google images “SOT “ and compare

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [BCX55](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BCP55_BCX55_BC55PA.pdf) NPN power transistor.

Comment: Many thanks, appreciated.

Comment: Hi Spehro Pefhany. I got to this transistor today again, having to remove with much effort. I definitely have the wrong tools. Anyway, the component was a pnp transistor. I actually though it funny as the emitter, pin 3, would then be coupled to the positive rail via the rather large cap next to it, in the case being a npn. Therefor I needed to ask as the first thought I had was a 1A positive LDO regulator. Makes more sense for me now, but still not the culprit on the circuit I had in mind.

Comment: Q means it's definitely a transistor.

Comment: 100%. But therefor also I know many may become irritated here when questions about markings are asked, google is not much the friend. Its difficult to always know, just delays repair time.